# How does the extend() function work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I saw this in a plugin:

```
var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

How does it work?

What does [`extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) do?

Comment: You can read about it on the jQuery documentation but I guess [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options) is a better explanation for it.

Comment: jQuery has good docs. http://api.jquery.com/ Just type the method name in the *Search jQuery* field.

Comment: I think Todd want to know how jQuery.extend works, NOT how to use it. For example, does it loop through each property to create a whole new object, or does it use prototype inheritance in some awesome way.

Answer (score 189):

## Multiple Parameters

The documentation isn't precise in explaining how extend works, so I ran a little test:

```
var a = {foo: 1, bar: 1};
var b = {foo: 2, baz: 2};
var c = {foo: 3};
var r = jQuery.extend(a,b,c);
console.log("A: Foo=" + a.foo + " Bar=" + a.bar + " Baz=" + a.baz);
console.log("B: Foo=" + b.foo + " Bar=" + b.bar + " Baz=" + b.baz);
console.log("C: Foo=" + c.foo + " Bar=" + c.bar + " Baz=" + c.baz);
console.log("R: Foo=" + r.foo + " Bar=" + r.bar + " Baz=" + r.baz);
console.log("A === R?: " + (a === r));
```

(The `console.log` function is intended to work in Firebug; replace it with alert() or some other output function if you like).

The results are:

```
A: Foo=3 Bar=1 Baz=2
B: Foo=2 Bar=undefined Baz=2
C: Foo=3 Bar=undefined Baz=undefined
R: Foo=3 Bar=1 Baz=2
A === R?: true
```

By this we can see that jQuery.extend():

- Starts with the object provided by the first parameter.
- Adds to it any property in the second parameter. If the property already exists in the first parameter, it is overwritten. The object for the second parameter is unchanged.
- Repeats the above with any subsequent parameter.
- Returns the first parameter.

This is useful for combining user and default option-objects together to get a complete set of options:

```
function foo(userOptions) {
  var defaultOptions = {
    foo: 2,
    bar: 2
  };
  var someOtherDefaultOptions = {
    baz: 3
  };

  var allOptions = jQuery.extend(
    defaultOptions,
    someOtherDefaultOptions,
    userOptions
  );
  doSomething(allOptions);
}

foo({foo:1, baz:1});
```

Note that "null" is a valid value for overwriting, but "undefined" isn't. You might be able to make use of this.

```
var a = {foo: "a", bar: "a"};
var b = {foo: null, bar: undefined};
jQuery.extend(a,b);
console.log("A: Foo=" + a.foo + " Bar=" + a.bar);
```

Results in:

```
A: Foo=null Bar=a
```

## Single Parameter

If you pass just one object to `jQuery.extend()`, then jQuery assumes that the `jQuery` object *itself* is the "first" parameter (ie: the one to be modified), and your object is the "second" (ie: the one to add to the first). So:

```
console.log( "Before: " + jQuery.foo );
jQuery.extend({foo:1});
console.log( "After: " + jQuery.foo );
```

Results in:

```
Before: undefined
After: 1
```

Comment: so if b.baz was an object say `{zed: 'dark'}` rather than `2` and you set `r.baz.zed = 'light'`, what would the value of `b.baz.zed` be? ie are the properties copied or merged by reference?

Comment: to answer my own question, `b.baz.zed` would be `light` - ie values are merged by reference. see a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erichbschulz/2pKRk/9/)

Comment: $.extend( true, object1, object2 ); and $.extend(  object1, object2 ); difference...

Comment: The only thing missing, I think, is whether objects/properties are copied or referenced

Answer (score 33):

It **merges the content of one object to another**. If we pass two  objects, **second object properties are added to the first object / first parameter**

```
Ex: $.extend(object1, object2);
```

Now **object1 contains properties of object2**

If we want to **merge two objects**, then we need to pass empty object in the first parameter

```
Ex: var newObject = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

Now **newObject contains both properties of object1 and object2**.

Answer (score 12):

From jQuery Documentation

> Merge the contents of two or more
>   objects together into the first
>   object.

**In a plugin context:** If the user does not set the optional parameters for the function, then a default value will be used instead.

Comment: This answer should be in a comment.

Comment: Thank You JOBG !!

Answer (score 8):

How does extend() work in jQuery? **[Resolved]**

jQuery have deep copy and light copy. The first boolean decide it, true for deep and false for light.

For example:

- jQuery.extend(false, {'a' : {'a1': 1}}, {'a': {'a2': 2}})

  the result will be: 
  {'a': {'a2': 2}} because this is light copy just compare level 1.

  [image]
- jQuery.extend(true, {'a' : {'a1': 1}}, {'a': {'a2': 2}})

  the result will be:
  {'a': {'a1': 1, 'a2': 2}} This is deep copy with many level of object (just like level of array)

  [image]
- jQuery.extend(a,b,c) with a, b, c is object or array. The flow overrite will be b->a, c ->a (b overrite a, c override a ...) this function will return a and a also change value too.

**Advanced Examples:**

- jQuery.extend({'number_param': 1})

  In case you just pass one param. jQuery will extend itself. console.log(jQuery['number_param']) will output 1.

  [image]
- jQuery.extend(1, {'number_param': '2'}); This example is not append jQuery itself. The first parameter must be boolean. In this case it will return {'number_param': '2'} and jQuery not get updated.

  [image]
- jQuery.extend(a, b, c, d ,e , f); The order merge will be . b ->a ,
  c -> a, d -> a, e -> a, f ->a (b override a, c override a ...) . And result return will be a.

  with a= {'p': 1}. 
  jQuery.extend(a, {'p': 2},{'p': 3},{'p': 4},{'p': 5}) will return a, and a = {'p': 6}. The number parameters pass to this function is unlimited.

  [image]

Comment: From the [docks](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) "Warning: Passing false for the first argument is not supported."

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is to extend an existing object. For e.g. if we have a template object and we want to extend that by adding more properties or override existing properties, jquery extend can be useful.

```
var carObjectTemplate = {
"make": "honda",
"model":"city",
"mileage":"20",
"variant":"petrol"
```

};

now if we want to extend it,
   `$.extend(true, {"color":"red"}, carObjectTemplate, {"model": 'amaze'});`
   it will give us ouput, extending carObjectTemplate and adding

```
{"color":"red"} property and overriding "model" property from "city" to "amaze"
```

first boolean parameter true/false is to indicate if we need a deep or shallow copy

Comment: What means deep or shallow copy?

Answer (score 0):

It does exactly this

> **Description**: Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the
>   first object.

More at [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Comment: One line answers and links to docs are not of much use as an answer and should be left in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

### Merge two objects, modifying the first.

```js
var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: { weight: 52, price: 100 },
  cherry: 97
};
var object2 = {
  banana: { price: 200 },
  durian: 100
};

$( "#object1" ).append( JSON.stringify( object1 ) );
$( "#object2" ).append( JSON.stringify( object2 ) );

// Merge object2 into object1
$.extend( object1, object2 );
 
// Assuming JSON.stringify - not available in IE<8
$( "#result" ).append( JSON.stringify( object1 ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>object1</h3>
<code id="object1"></code>
<h3>object2</h3>
<code id="object2"></code>
<h3>$.extend( object1, object2 )</h3>
<code id="result"></code>
```

### Merge two objects recursively, modifying the first.

```js
var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: { weight: 52, price: 100 },
  cherry: 97
};
var object2 = {
  banana: { price: 200 },
  durian: 100
};

$( "#object1" ).append( JSON.stringify( object1 ) );
$( "#object2" ).append( JSON.stringify( object2 ) );
 
// Merge object2 into object1, recursively
$.extend( true, object1, object2 );
 
// Assuming JSON.stringify - not available in IE<8
$( "#result" ).append( JSON.stringify( object1 ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>object1</h3>
<code id="object1"></code>
<h3>object2</h3>
<code id="object2"></code>
<h3>$.extend( true, object1, object2 )</h3>
<code id="result"></code>
```

### Merge defaults and options, without modifying the defaults. This is a common plugin development pattern.

```js
var defaults = {
  validate: false,
  limit: 5,
  name: "foo"
};
var options = {
  validate: true,
  name: "bar"
};

// Merge defaults and options, without modifying defaults
var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

$("#defaults").append(JSON.stringify(defaults));
$("#options").append(JSON.stringify(options));
$("#settings").append(JSON.stringify(settings));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>defaults</h3>
<code id="defaults"></code>
<h3>options</h3>
<code id="options"></code>
<h3>$.extend( {}, defaults, options )</h3>
<code id="settings"></code>
```