# Combine two object into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript I would like to combine two objects into one. I got

```
{
  test: false,
  test2: false
}
```

and

```
{
  test2: true
}
```

I tried to use `$.extend`, `$.merge` but all I get as an output is

```
{
  test2: true
}
```

How to get output like this

```
{
  test: false,
  test2: true
}
```

EDIT: Actually I have nested objects. What I need is to combine `a` and `b` as follows:

```
var a = { test: false, test2: { test3: false, test4: false } };
var b = { test2: { test4: true } };
// desired combined result:
{ test: false, test2: { test3: false, test4: true } }
```

but the actual result I get removes `test3` from the nested `test2` object.

Comment: $.extend() should work. show what code you tried.

Comment: what is the rule for the final object to get test2: true, instead of test2: false?

Comment: what I need is var a = {
    test: false,
    test2: {
  test3: false,
  test4: false
 }
};

var b = {
    test2: {
  test4: true
 }
}; and get { test: false, test2: { test3: false, test4: true  } } but I get test3 removed after

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does extend() work in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528744/how-does-extend-work-in-jquery)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var a = {
    test: false,
    test2: false
};

var b = {
    test2: true
};

var c = $.extend(a, b);
```

This will overwrite all properties on object `a` with a result of:

```
{
    test: false,
    test2: true
}
```

If you want a new, fresh object call `.extend` like so:

```
var c = $.extend({}, a, b);
```

This will do the same job, but it leaves object `a` untouched and creates a new object. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

---

**update**

In your comment you updated the object structures. Well, what you need there is a such called "deep clone". This is just one more parameter for the `$.extend()` call, like so:

```
var c = $.extend(true, a, b); // a gets overwritten
var c = $.extend(true, {}, a, b); // new object is created
```

Comment: Hi, yes I works, I put wrong example, what I need is var a = {
    test: false,
    test2: {
  test3: false,
  test4: false
 }
};

var b = {
    test2: {
  test4: true
 }
}; and get { test: false, test2: { test3: false, test4: true  } } but I get test3 removed after