# combine two Json object into one

Tags: json

I have two json object as mentioned below

Var arr1 = [id: 1, name : "Vivek", gender: "male", dob: "09-02-1983", address: ""]

Var arr2 = [id: 1, address: "Bangalore"]

Now based on id I have to update the address without losing the existing values.

Please suggest some approach to resolve this

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using. Net framework along with jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var arr1 = [id: 1, name : "Vivek", gender: "male", dob: "09-02-1983", address: ""];
var arr2 = [id: 1, address: "Bangalore"];

var combinedArray = $.merge(arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can use the .extend method. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

*Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.*

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

Also see this: [How does extend() work in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528744/how-does-extend-work-in-jquery)

Comment: What if the property address in object arr1 has some values on it will it override

Comment: Please describe what your expected output should be and the different cases.