# What is the purpose of first boolean parameter in $.extend

Tags: jquery

Initially i have a doubt how $.extend works. I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528744/how-does-extend-work-in-jquery) question.But I'm confused about the following code segment

```
$.extend(true,{},{foo:2})
$.extend({},{foo:2})
```

Both return `{foo:2}`.

I am very clear about second code statement. How does first statement work? What is the difference between first and second statement? If both are same, What is the purpose of first statement? If not, why does both returns same result?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It creates a deep copy, I think an example could show you what it does

```js
var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).appendTo($log)
  }
})();

function test(deep) {
  var obj = {
    prop1: 1,
    obj12: {
      prop1: 1
    }
  };

  var cpy = deep ? $.extend(true, {}, obj) : $.extend({}, obj);

  cpy.obj12.prop1 = 'changed';
  log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  log(JSON.stringify(cpy));
}
log('without the deep param')
test();
log('with deep')
test(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

If you look at the generated results the `obj12` value is actually copied to `cpy` when `deep` was not used.

Comment: Good explanation. takes a little time to understand

Comment: Hi Arun, What does Aakash's code do? Any explsnstions on that?

Comment: @user3801433 it is the same principle.... the non deep version just copies the values to the target to... the deep version will do a recursive extend call

Comment: I don't understand his code really.prop1 and prop4 also must be empty as prop2 in case1? isn't?

Comment: @user3801433 `foo1` has `prop1`, `obj1`, `prop4` properties.... then when `foo2` is merged.. it gets the new property `prop6`, since both of them has `obj1` the value of `foo1` is overridden by value of `foo2`

Comment: +1 somewhat clear.So if itsnt deep, it will overwrite values of existing keys. Am i clear?

Answer (score 1):

Passing true as the first argument helps merging the values of the same key in both the objects, else it simply overwrites the value on first object with the value from second object with same key. The following example should help making it clear

```
var foo1 = {
  prop1: 1,
  obj1: { prop2: 2, prop3: 3 },
  prop4: 4
};
var foo2 = {
  obj1: { prop3: 32 },
  prop6: 6
};

/*overwrites the value for key: obj1 */
$.extend( foo1, foo2 );
//{"prop1":1,"obj1":{"prop3":32},"prop4":4,"prop6":6}  

/*merges the value for key: obj1 */
$.extend( true, foo1, foo2 );
//{"prop1":1,"obj1":{"prop2":2,"prop3":32},"prop4":4,"prop6":6}
```

Comment: It's also interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Ans 1: The merge performed by $.extend() is not recursive by default; if a property of the first object is itself an object or array, it will be completely overwritten by a property with the same key in the second or subsequent object. The values are not merged. However, by passing true for the first function argument, objects will be recursively merged.

Ans 2: the first will perform a recursive merged(deep copy) where as second will do a normal merge,overriding the first object pass any...

Ans 3: as both are not same first one will return a recursive merged object whereas second will return a object with no recursive

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.extend </title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Default Objects</p> 
<div id="default"></div>
<p>seconrio 1 : merging object using recursive (deep copy)</p> 
<div id="seconrio1"></div>
<p>here in this only price value is override using recursive and banana object</p> 
  
<p>seconrio 2 :  Merge object1 and object2, without using recursive (deep copy)</p> 
<div id="seconrio2"></div>
 <p>here in this whole banana object value is override</p> 
<script>
  var object1 = {
    apple: 0,
    banana: { weight: 52, price: 100 },
    cherry: 97
  };
  var object2 = {
    banana: { price: 200 },
    durian: 100
  };

  var printObj = typeof JSON !== "undefined" ? JSON.stringify : function( obj ) {
    var arr = [];
    $.each( obj, function( key, val ) {
      var next = key + ": ";
      next += $.isPlainObject( val ) ? printObj( val ) : val;
      arr.push( next );
    });
    return "{ " +  arr.join( ", " ) + " }";
  };
 $( "#default" ).append( "<div><b>object1 -- </b>" + printObj( object1 ) + "</div>" );
 $( "#default" ).append( "<div><b>object2 -- </b>" + printObj( object2 ) + "</div>" );


  // Merge object2 into object1, recursively
  $.extend( true, object1, object2 );
  
  $( "#seconrio1" ).append( "<div><b>object1 -- </b>" + printObj( object1 ) + "</div>" );
  $( "#seconrio1" ).append( "<div><b>object2 -- </b>" + printObj( object2 ) + "</div>" );



  // Merge object1 and object2, without recursively
  var settings = $.extend( {}, object1, object2 );
 
 
  $( "#seconrio2" ).append( "<div><b>object1 -- </b>" + printObj( settings ) + "</div>" );
  $( "#seconrio2" ).append( "<div><b>object2 -- </b>" + printObj( object2 ) + "</div>" );

</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: waswwm, Same answer as Aakash and Johnny. But u answered separately for all   of my questions. Thanks